# importing eventListener in node/webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I'm doing a project for an online course and I've recently submited my project for review.  One of the changes I was told to make is that I need to import my eventListener from my formHandler.js file into my index.js file in my client folder.  I don't know how to do this.  How do I import an eventListener from one js file to another?  I don't even understand why this is necessary because the whole app is fully functional but apparently I'm required to import the eventListener into index.js in order to pass the project.  These are the two files I'm working with:

formHandler.js

```
import { postData } from "./postData"
import { updateUI } from "./updateUI"
import { checkURL } from "./checkURL"

document.getElementById('generate').addEventListener('click', handleSubmit);

function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault()

    //event.preventDefault()

    // check what text was put into the form field
    let place = document.getElementById('place').value
    let date = document.getElementById('date').value
    postData('/postData', {place: place, date: date})
    .then(updateUI)

};

export { handleSubmit }
```

index.js:

```
import { checkForName } from './js/nameChecker'
import { handleSubmit } from './js/formHandler'
import { updateUI } from './js/updateUI'
import { postData } from './js/postData'
import { apiCall } from './js/apiCall'
import { checkURL } from './js/checkURL'
import { removeTrip } from './js/cookies'
import { resultsCheck } from './js/cookies'

import './styles/form.scss'
import './styles/header.scss'
import './styles/style.scss'
import './styles/footer.scss'

export {
    handleSubmit,
    updateUI,
    postData,
    apiCall,
    checkURL,
    removeTrip,
    resultsCheck
}
```

Thanks,
Michael

EDIT: One of the comments below suggested that they may want me to attach the lIstener in index instead of the form handler.  What does this mean and how do I do this?

Comment: Go back and tell them to look at your files. You're already exporting the callback function, that's what the `export`is doing. Perhaps they want you to attach the lIstener in index instead of the form handler.

Comment: how do i attach the listener in index